# Rethrowing multiple instances of exception_ptr containing same exception

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Is the behavior of the following snippet well-defined?

```
std::exception_ptr eptr;

try {
  ...
} catch (...) {
  eptr = std::current_exception();
}

std::exception_ptr eptr2(eptr);

std::vector<std::exception_ptr> eptrs{eptr, eptr2};

for (auto& exc: eptrs) try {
  std::rethrow_exception(exc);
} catch(std::exception& e) {
  std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

If so, does this require that the exception object itself (not just exception_ptr) be copyable?

Comment: But when we rethrow one of two instances of the exception_ptr and the underlying exception is thrown, is it a copy of the original exception? Because there is still a second instance of exception_ptr containing the original exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot quote the standard, but looking at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception_ptr/)  for std::exception pointer it states:

> It is a shared pointer-like type: The pointed exception is **guaranteed to remain valid for as long as at least one exception_ptr points to it**, potentially extending its lifetime beyond the scope of a catch statement or across threads.

The exception_ptr itself may be copied:

> Being copied, including being copied a null-pointer value (or nullptr).

So yes, the behavior is defined.
Since it is a *shared pointer-like* type, there is no copy requirement for the contained exception object

This [article](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/copying_exceptions.html) explains it a bit further:

> The original proposal for the feature required that the exception was copied when it was captured with std::current_exception, but under pressure from implementors that use the "Itanium ABI" (which is actually used for other platforms too, such as 64-bit x86 linux and MacOSX), the requirement was lessened to allow reference counting the exceptions instead. The problem they cited was that **the ABI didn't store the copy constructor for exception objects**, so when you called std::current_exception() the information required to copy the object was not present.